# Assign different value if element exists

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to assign one of two values to a variable, depending on whether an element is present or not. I thought something like this should work...

```
$optsH = function(){
    if ( jQ('#options').length > 0 ) {
        return jQ('#options').outerHeight();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

... but no.

I know this should be simple, but it's been a long day.

Comment: "no" what? And what is `.length()`?

Comment: I don't any errors, but I also don't get a value assigned. My bad - it should be `.length`

Comment: you're assigning a function to a variable

Comment: I was intending to assign the value a function creates to a variable - is that bad?

Comment: and you don't need a function for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you just forgot to call your function;

```
$optsH = (function(){
    if ( jQ('#options').length > 0 ) {
        return jQ('#options').outerHeight();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
})()
```

If you want to optimise it though, this is a much better way:

```
$optsH = jQ('#options').outerHeight() || 0;
```

Comment: but yeah, your question is vague and not a question

Comment: You've nailed it - thanks. Sorry, I thought my intent was clear from the code I posted. You inferred the correct meaning anyway.

Comment: @verism yes, I guessed from the variable names. But in the future you should always say what you expect code to do, and what it's doing instead, even if it's obvious to you. It saves a lot of time in answering so you're more likely to get a response.

Answer (score 2):

The [`outerHeight`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) call will return null if the selector matches no elements, and null is falsy, so you should be able to do something like this:

```
$optsH = jQ('#options').outerHeight() || 0;
```

(I'm unable to test right now, but I'm pretty sure it should work.)

Comment: It works perfectly, but Dave already offered the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#input_field').val($('#options').length > 0 ? $('#options').outerHeight() : 0);
});
```

Comment: Where does it return the result?

Comment: fixed, :) sorry i was a little bit in a hurry :)

Answer (score 0):

If the element is not present `jQ('#options')` will return an empty collection, why another check?

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer.